# Simulate a SNMPV3 traps with Engine-time

Tags: snmp, net-snmp

I am trying to simulate a snmp v3 traps with engine time value.  long story short, our trap processor will receive first snmp v3 trap from any hosts but any subsequent trap will retun "*Error!*  Mangled value" and "SNMP-D-EAGENTUSMWINDOW-Agent REPORT [USM]: Not In Time Window". the only way to receive the v3 trap is to keep restarting the trap processor ..

i have been told that this was because that the trap does not have valid Engine-boot or Engine-Time, i have been using the following example to simulate the V3 traps, but it doesnt include Engine time so our trap processor will process this the first time, and give the error when it received the second time...

snmptrap -v 3 -e EngineID -u User -a SHA -A Auth Pass -x AES -X Pri-Pass -l authpriv -Z 123 destination IP:162 '' .1.3.6.1.4.1.3375.2.4.0.27 .1.3.6.1.4.1.3375.2.4.1.1 s "FAILED LOGIN FreddyFrogAA, Authentication failure"

Any help will be greatly appreciated

Ray

Answer (score 0):

When the SNMP trap receiver receives the first trap from sm_snmp, it creates an entry in its internal table representing its estimate of the time on the trap sender. The SNMP trap receiver will then compare its estimate with newly received traps (or other SNMP V3 responses) from that agent to verify that the packet is not being replayed.
Using sm_snmp to send the trap means that you execute sm_snmp each time. That means sm_snmp acts as if was just restarted and sets the engine boot time accordingly. To the trap receiver, this looks like an identical packet to the one already received. The trap receiver expects a packet with a timestamp that represents the remote agent having advanced by the time between the first and second traps. So the trap handler reports "Not In Time Window" if you wait longer than the time window (150 seconds) between sending the first and second traps.

Resolution:
If the message in the log is limited to SNMP-D-EAGENTUSMWINDOW-Agent REPORT [USM]: Not In Time Window. The trap receiver is working as designed and will continue to process traps as required.

If the  Trap receiver log is also reporting *Error!* Mangled value. Then the issue is with the device snmpagent not sending out the proper engine-boot or engine-time values.  The vendor needs to be consulted to resolve the issue with the snmp-agent.
It is recommended that the customer run a packet capture on the device for snmp v3 traffic to provide the vendor with the evidence so they can resolve the issue.